# How to scale an image source at a specific resolution

Tags: compositing-nodes

The scale node use a multiplier, 0.5 to reduce the image size by half and 2 to increase by 2. What should i use if i want to convert any image source at the desired resolution, for example i want to input a 4096*4096 or 512*512 and always get a 1024*1024 output and get the entire image not cropped.

Comment: did you try changing the scale from *relative* to *absolute*?

Comment: This question is kind of strange.  Blender texture coordinates by default go from 0..1.  If you UV unwrap a square and put a texture on it, you'll see the entire texture whether it is 4k, 2k, or 1k.  If that texture isn't square, it will be squished into a square.  In what context does the resolution of this texture really matter?

Comment: In absolute i can downscale correctly but if i upscale to a given resolution the image is cropped.

Yes it's important to get a specific resolution because i am making a node setup to check if a 2k texture is seamless and it translate a 2k texture for that: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?383624-Dark-Blender-(Official-Thread)-optimized-for-sculpting-and-game-asset-creation&p=3058915&viewfull=1#post3058915

Answer (score 4):

You can set the **Resolution Size** (in pixels) to the desired output size in the Scene Dimensions section of the properties window..

Using a [Scale Node](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/types/distort/scale.html?highlight=scale%20node),  will rescale an image connected to it to the predetermined output resolution.

[image]

If you want to double the number of pixels just render at 200% (in this example rendering a 512 x 512 pixel image will result in an image of 1024 x 1024 pixels). To cut the number of pixels in half, render at 50%.

[image]

Note that if the images are a **different aspect ratio** than the output, you have three choices:

**stretch**: deform the image to match within the aspect ratio of the container)

**Fit**: keep the images proportions but fill the remaining either with a transparent background or with black (if the "Use Alpha" option is unchecked)

or **Crop** Not stretching the image, resizing to fit vertically center cropping horizontally.

[image]