# Compositor - How do you get the same Math Result for any Render Size

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes

Any time I change Render Size it ruins all of my node-tree setup.
Common workflow in compositor is to work in some lower resolution to set wanted effect. Like 50% or 25% of final size.
But many values are based on current image size on input.

Does there exist any math combination that can be applied to a node-tree to protect the result? A math equation that can equally increase or decrease values in one place?

This gif example is using the same node-tree to generate a lens flare.
Rendered on 10%, 25%, 50%, 100%

[image: animated gif of composited effects rendered at different percents]

[image]

Comment: you could use a scale node in stretch mode. See: [Compositor renders video zoomed in](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19328/compositor-renders-video-zoomed-in/19329#19329) or: [How to scale an image source at a specific resolution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55614/how-to-scale-an-image-source-at-a-specific-resolution/55644#55644)

Comment: I  think you missed the point. With scale node I can keep result same only in case I scale render at 100% and do all node tree calculation on 100% size, that helps to save render time but totally waste compositing time. http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=126105

Comment: Unfortunately that is the only way you are going to get the same results with different image sizes.The issue is that some of the operations are pixel dependent and won'r rescale correctly.

Comment: @Rami Thanks again :) I'm not going to thank you for each (spelling/grammar) fix, so take it generally :) I wanted to send you a bounty, but there is not an option for such a thing, hm.

Comment: No worries and its cool.

Answer (score 8):

The current compositor is not relatively aware. Hence some pixel based nodes give different on different resolutions. There is a new design for the compositor that will overcome this issue, but this still needs a lot of development time. https://developer.blender.org/T53790

Comment: Thanks, it's a shame, any chance for same workaround?

Comment: Inside blender there is no work around to my knowledge. Normally I composite in the highest resolution (100%) and downscale afterwards using image magic.

Comment: I would love to so :) but my comp is not fast enough for complex node-trees :) Current situation also make totally impossible sharing node groups with others. I hope your link is a near future. Thanks